# Raspberry pi not booting nor screen showing any colors

Tags: hardware, boot-issues, activity-led

So I just took off my raspberry pi and clean it with wet tower and dry it completely off. When i then boot into it, it was completely normal then I started to notice that the green light is not flashing anymore so I unplug the power supply and plug it back in but this time the green light is not showing then I even plug raspberry pi monitor into it and the monitor just showing blank/black as if it were not even powered on.

So is this a possible hardware damage or just image corruption?

I have running raspberry pi for 24/7 for least 2 months already and didn't run into any issues

Comment: Sounds like it can't read the SD card.  Leave it to dry for a day or so.  What happened to it?  What model is it?  If it is Pi 3 then you could try netboot.

Comment: Actually that helps, cause for some reason yesterday my SD card does not want to insert into it all the way but today it works and thanks. P.S. I just notice it able to insert it into it more depper